# zsh:killed amplify, getting this error even after uninstalling, how to rectify?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I tried to install and run amplify cli but it was giving me some issues, so after a few installs and uninstalls I suddenly ended up with this error in my vscode terminal, how do I go about it?

I tried all the possible solutions from stackoverflow but nothing has worked so putting it out here